# API routes on react and express app giving 404 on Heroku

Tags: reactjs, express, heroku, multer

I am building a simple mern app that works fine on my local environment, but when deploying to Heroku, it serves the react app fine but 404s on the API calls. I can't seems to figure out the issue. I'm sending requests using Axios. I checked the network requests and they all look good, but still come back 404.

i have tried changing the scripts inside my package.json and still no luck.

Here's the server code... Any idea why this is failing?

```
const express = require('express');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const fileUpload = require('express-fileupload')
const cors = require('cors')

 
const app = express();
const routes = require('./routes');
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3001;
// Setup middlewares

app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(express.json());

app.use(fileUpload())
app.use(cors())
// app.use(methodOverride('_method'))

 if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
  app.use(express.static('client/build'));

}

app.use("/",routes);
 
require('./services/passport');
// Connect database
// mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGODB_URI || 'mongodb://localhost/userstockitem', { useNewUrlParser: true, useCreateIndex: true, useUnifiedTopology: true, useFindAndModify: false });
 

mongoose.connect(MONGODB_URI || 'mongodb://localhost/profile', { useNewUrlParser: true, useCreateIndex: true, useUnifiedTopology: true, useFindAndModify: false });

mongoose.connection.on('connected', ()=>{
  console.log('mongoose is connected')
})

 

app.listen(PORT,()=>{
  console.log(`listening on PORT ${PORT}`)
});
`
```

and here's my package.json

```
{
  "name": "blogster",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "engines": {
    "node": "12.16.1",
    "npm": "6.13.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "if-env NODE_ENV=production && npm run start:prod || npm run start:dev",
    "start:prod": "node index.js",
    "start:dev": "concurrently \"nodemon --ignore 'client/*'\" \"npm run client\"",
    "client": "cd client && npm run start",
    "install": "cd client && npm install",
    "build": "cd client && npm run build",
    "heroku-postbuild": "npm run build"
  },
   "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "concurrently": "^5.0.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.19.0",
    "bcryptjs": "^2.4.3",
    "body-parser": "^1.19.0",
    "chart.js": "^2.9.4",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "ejs": "^3.1.5",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "express-fileupload": "^1.2.0",
    "gridfs-stream": "^1.1.1",
    "if-env": "^1.0.4",
    "jwt-simple": "^0.5.6",
    "method-override": "^3.0.0",
    "mongoose": "^5.9.18",
    "multer": "^1.4.2",
    "multer-gridfs-storage": "^4.2.0",
    "mysql": "^2.17.1",
    "passport": "^0.4.1",
    "passport-jwt": "^4.0.0",
    "passport-local": "^1.0.0",
    "plotly.js": "^1.54.2",
    "react": "^17.0.1",
    "react-chartjs-2": "^2.11.1",
    "react-helmet": "^6.1.0",
    "react-images-upload": "^1.2.8",
    "react-live-clock": "^5.0.13",
    "react-plotly.js": "^2.4.0",
    "react-sound": "^1.2.0",
    "validator": "^13.1.1"
  }
}
```

My react routes in case that would be an issue

```
const multer = require('multer')

const upload = multer({dest:''}) 


  router.route('/myimages')
 .get(requireAuth,getMyImages)
 .post(requireAuth,upload.single('file'),postMyImages)
```

my controller :

```
 postMyImages: async (req, res) => {
    const { fileName,filePath } = req.body;
    console.log(req.body,'console.log filename and filepath')
 
    if(req.files === null) {
      return res.status(400).json({msf:'no file uploaded'})
    }
    try {
      const file = req.files.file
 
      file.mv(`${__dirname}/../client/public/images/${file.name}`,async (err)=>{
        if(err){
          console.error(err)
          return res.status(500).send(err)
        }
         const newImage = await new Image({fileName:file.name,filePath:`/images/${file.name}`, user: req.user._id}).save();
        req.user.myImages.push(newImage);
        console.log(newImage,'new image')
        await req.user.save();
         
        return res.status(200).json(newImage);

      })}catch (e) {
      console.log('error not hitting ')
      return res.status(403).json({ e });
    }
     
  },
  getMyImages: async (req, res) => {
    try {
      const images = await Image.find({ user: req.user._id });
      return res.json(images);
    } catch (e) {
      return res.status(403).json({ e });
    }
   
  }
```

my axios call

```
componentDidMount = () => {
    this.getMyImage()
    console.log('getting images....')
}


getMyImage = () => {
    axios.get('/api/user/myimages',{headers: { 'authorization': localStorage.getItem('token')}})
    .then((response)=>{
        this.setState({myImages:response.data.reverse()})
        console.log("myImages:response.data ", response.data)
    })
}

handleRequest = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault()
    const data = new FormData();
    const {file} = this.state
    data.append('file', file)
    
    axios.post('/api/user/myimages',data,{ 'Content-Type':'multipart/form-data',headers: { 'authorization': localStorage.getItem('token')}})
    .then((response)=>{
        const {fileName,filePath} = response.data
        console.log(response.data,'response.data filename and filepath')
        this.setState({uploadedFile:response.data})
        this.getMyImage()
     })
     
     
}
```

Comment: Your  problem is that you did not specify server's url and port number here: axios.post('/api/user/myimages',data,{ 'Content-Type':'multipart/form-data',headers: { 'authorization': localStorage.getItem('token')}})

Answer (score 1):

Have you added your `.ENV` File on Heroku's repo ?

Comment: hmm, no im not sure if i have. I m not aware that I have to specify anything on heroku. if so i might need to learn about it, im new.